# Including large js dependency in Vue PWA with webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, babeljs, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli

I'm working on a simple boggle like word game built with the Vue CLI. I found a list of words that I used to create a dictionary object because I read it's faster to lookup keys in an object than values in an array.

```
const WordDictionary = {
  aa: true,
  aah: true,
  aahed: true,
  aahing: true,
  ...
}
```

I use the dictionary to check if a word is valid. This file ends up being approx 1.3mb. When I build for production or serve from the development server it takes a long time to process.

I think the problem is with Babel because I get this message when the build process finally finishes.

`[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of word-dictionary.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.`

How can I configure the Vue CLI / webpack / babel build process to exclude this large file? Is there a better method for including a large dictionary like this into a PWA? (Definitely will add caching with a service worker once I figure that part out)

Comment: Have you tried ignoring the file with the `ignore` property in `.babelrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adam's comment pointed me in the right direction. I used the [exclude option for babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/options#exclude). I edited my `babel.config.js` to look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app',
  ],
  exclude: ['word-dictionary.js'],
};
```

but it only worked for the development server. To get it to work for the production build I spent a long night reading the [documentation on webpack config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-exclude) and the [documentation on webpack-chain](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain) and came up with a solution. In `vue.config.js` I added the following:

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  config.module.rules.get('js').exclude.add(/[\\/]src[\\/]assets[\\/]word-dictionary[\\.]js/);
  config.optimization.merge({
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
        dictionary: {
          minChunks: 1,
          name: 'dictionary',
          test: /[\\/]src[\\/]assets[\\/]word-dictionary[\\.]js/,
        },
      },
    },
  });
},
```

which excludes the dictionary from being processed by babel and also splits it into its own chunk. It was helpful to use the `vue-cli-service inspect` command (or run `vue ui` and run the `inspect task`) to see the webpack config generated by the Vue CLI

I actually ended up not using this solution as I decided to fetch the dictionary as plaintext after the component is loaded and to use indexOf to search for the words.